# Removing the space an element occupies without hiding it

Tags: css

I know that I can hide an element without removing the space it would occupy by using `visibility: hidden`. What I want to do is the exact opposite: I want to render the rest of the page as if the element wasn't on the page, but keep the element visible.

The reason I'm asking is because I have a centered 950px-wide layout to which I want to add a little box on the left side of the screen. It would look kinda like this:

[image: Mockup]

Right now I have a `<div>` that holds the side box as the top element in my 950px page wrapper, which is also a `<div>`. To the side box I've applied `position: relative` and `left: -200px` (box width) to move it to the side, but that still leaves me with the main content being pushed down. Am I approaching the problem correctly? Is there a logical way to remove the vertical space that was left behind by the side box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `position: absolute;`. The element will no longer be part of the document flow, and you can position it relative to its closest non-`static`ally positioned ancestor.

Comment: I set the page wrapper (its ancestor) to `position: relative` and the side box to `position: absolute`, which fixed my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Position relative will still occupy the space. Try position:absolute; It will place the element absolutely inside its parent but above all of its siblings.